# add overlay on map by using source , destination lat long points

Tags: dictionary

I am working on Google map API V3
I have done with display route between source to destination by using its lat long points,
But i need to show a area highlight which comes under source and destination lat long respectively

Answer (score 0):

Check 'Polygons' overlay in the api reference.